# getLayers getLength from LayerGroup is 0?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

With this function I get the LayerGroup list that I can parse and identify the Group "Runs" I want. 
Until this point it is working.
But `var length = layers.getLength` always returns `0`.

```
function getActiveLayer(layerName, picID) {
  // get layerGroups
  var layers = map.getLayers();
  var length = layers.getLength(),
    l;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    l = layers.item(i);
    var lt = l.get('title');
    // check for layers within groups
    if (lt === 'Runs') { // Title of Group
      // get layers from Runs
      var layers = l.getLayers();
      //get length
      var length = layers.getLength(),
        l;
      if (length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {

          l = layers.item(i);
          var lt = l.get('title');
          // check for Layer Title
          if (lt === layerName) { // Title if Layer
            var innerLayers = l.getSource().getFeatureById(picID).getGeometry().getCoordinates();
            return innerLayers;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }


};
```

[getLayers from map and LayerGroup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFXKP.jpg)

The Upper one is the getLayers from map.
The lower one is the getLauers from "Runs".

Can somebody explain why length is actual 0?l

**Edit:**

I updated the code:

```
 function getActiveLayer(layerName, picID) {
  // get layerGroups
  var layers = map.getLayers();
  var length = layers.getLength();
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    l = layers.item(i);
    var lt = l.get('title');
    // check for layers within groups
    if (lt === 'Runs') { // Title of Group
      // get layers from Runs
      var layers = l.getLayers().getArray();
      //get length
      var length2 = layers.getLength();
      console.log(length2);
      if (length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < length2; i++) {

          l = layers.item(i);
          var lt = l.get('title');
          // check for Layer Title
          if (lt === layerName) { // Title if Layer
            var innerLayers = l.getSource().getFeatureById(picID).getGeometry().getCoordinates();
            return innerLayers;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

console.log(length2); is still 0.

Comment: Please add a working snippet or create a http://jsfiddle.net that demonstrates the issue you have.

Comment: How did you set the title as "Run"?

Comment: @ Chase Choi
here is the definition:

    var runs = new ol.layer.Group({
          'title': 'Runs',
          visible: true,
          layers: layer,
    });

Answer (score 0):

`var length = layers.getLength(), l;`

This is horrible code and you most likely did not do it on purpose. Also see: [comma separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769922/x-y-z-comma-assignment-in-javascript)
At this position, you probably just wanted to get length from l:

`var length = l.getLength();`

You built a particularly nasty snippet. Run the code below. You probably expect it to go 3 time throught the loop - it does not.

There is no *block-level-scope* in javascript, only *function-level-scope*, so `var x=y` inside a `for` does not define the variable only for the for block but for the whole function.

Look at variable shadowing questions, which [explain the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11113494/304179) in detail.
Use unique variable names. Never try to do variable shadowing, it's really bad practice!

```js
function badpractice(number) {

  var length = number;
  console.log('length before loop', length);
  for(var i=0;i < length;i++){
    console.log('length before for assign', length);
    var length = i;
    console.log('length after for assign', length);
  }
  console.log('length after loop', length);
};

badpractice(3);
```

Comment: HI, Thank you for your advice! I appreciate it alaways if someone takes the time to point out an error.

But my problem is not solved. the length of "Runs" is still 0.

Comment: append your updated code to the question so we can check it

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution. here you go:

```
   function getActiveLayer(layerName,picID) {
        var layers = map.getLayers();
            var length = layers.getLength();
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                l = layers.item(i);
                var lt = l.get('title');
                // check for layers within groups
                if (lt === 'Runs') { // Title of Group
                  var layers = l.getLayers().getArray();
                  var length = l.getLayers().getArray().length;
                  // loop over layers
                    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                      l = layers[i];
                      var lt = l.get('title');
                      // check for Layer Title
                      if (lt === layerName) { // Title if Layer
                        var innerLayers = l.getSource().getFeatureById(picID).getGeometry().getCoordinates();
                        return innerLayers; // return coord of feature
                      }
                    }
                }
            }


      };
```